# Upload data to AWS S3 - EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, error-handling, endpoint

Following this good tutorial https://medium.com/bilesanmiahmad/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-in-python-68757a1867c6 I wrote a code with the purpose to upload a file to a S3 bucket:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError

ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False
```

I specified the parameters as follows:

```
uploaded = upload_to_aws('path/to/my/file/test.csv', 'name-of-s3-bucket', 'test.csv')
```

When I now try to execute this, I got the following error:

```
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://name-of-s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.csv"
```

Is there something I specified in the wrong way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Is your region correctly specified as N.Virginia in ~/.aws/config file?
The most common reason for this error is that your region isn't set properly. And since I see it's a standard .s3.amazonaws.com, you might wanna check if your region is set to us-east-1 in the config file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does my region has to be specified as N. Virginia even if the region I am actually logged in is Frankfurt?

Comment: No. I guessed N.V. based on your S3 url. Normally the url generated for S3 is of two types: with region(for other than N.V.) and without. Either your frankfurt region code is not correctly specified in the config file or the bucket is not in the right region(my guess is more inclined towards this one).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will check this. Hopefully this is the reason why it does not work.